# Render Layers Without Displaying Them In 3D Viewport

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, render-layers

I wam new to blender. I have a large forest I would like to render. Blender gets extreme lag and usually completely crashes when I display the whole scene. I split the forest into multiple layers. Is there a way to render all the necessary layers without displaying them in the 3d view?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to lock rendered layers?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/is-there-a-way-to-lock-rendered-layers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, however there might be better ways of handling this.

Disable [*Lock layers to scene*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Navigating/Layers#Locking_to_the_scene) in the *3D view > Header*.

Now you can set the Scene layers in *Properties > Renderlayers* to the layers you want to render (in this case, 1, 2, and 3)

[image]

Note that only layer 1 is visible in the viewport.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it later and tell you if it works.