# Why are the renderlayers rendering black?

Tags: rendering, render-layers

I understand there are a lot of questions similar to this but non of the solutions worked for me. I have a camera, I have lighting, rendering other things worked for me, I've restarted, etc.

Here's the rendered view for one of the renderlayers:

[image]

Here's the rendered view for the other one:

[image]

But when I render:

[image]

Black for both of the renders.

.blend:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible you could upload your .blend?

Comment: @gandalf3 edited to add .blend

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the *Scene* layers corresponding to your renderlayers are not enabled:

[image]

If you enable the right scene layers (or all of them), then it works as expected.

Note that by default the [3D view layers are linked to the scene layers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3649/599). You may want to turn this off by toggling *Lock Camera and Layers* in *3D view > Header*:

[image]

---

Also note that there is nothing on the *Lines* renderlayer; perhaps you meant to select this layer instead?

[image]

Comment: Great thanks! I'm new to using render layers so I thought I made a stupid mistake. Thanks for the quick answer